# Symmetric stress tensor in fluid Mechanics for a cube

Tags: fluid-dynamics, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain

In textbooks and online I read that conservation of angular momentum of a cubic element of fluid guarantees the symmetry of the stress tensor. I am not sure how to make this work. See the figure below, I am just considering the $x$-$y$ plane. I think that the face of the cube doesn't have to rotate because we are considering a fixed cube in space, otherwise it would. So there are 2 options:

1. If  I am conserving z-angular momentum at point C (the center) by prescribing that forces times the arms with respect to C are zero. Pressure forces, gravity and momentum fluxes all go through the center so they have zero arm. I am left with

   $$2\tau_{xy}\mathrm dx/2 + \frac{\partial\tau_{xy}}{\partial y}\mathrm dx^2/2 = 2\tau_{yx}\mathrm dy/2 + 
   \frac{\partial\tau_{yx}}{\partial x}\mathrm dy^2/2$$

   which doesn't give me $\tau_{xy}=\tau_{yx}$.
2. If  I am conserving z-angular momentum at point p, then I will have the add all the pressure terms and momentum fluxes terms plus gravity, and that doesn't give me $\tau_{xy}=\tau_{yx}$ either.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Try to have a look at here, p.13-14, only in Italian, maybe google translate could help https://gitlab.com/davideMontagnani/fluidmechanics-ita/-/blob/master/qa/qa.pdf

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

I'd evaluate moments w.r.t. point $P$, but it really doesn't matter the choice of the pole.

What you miss in your procedure is that you're writing equations for an elementary (infinitesimal) domain, and this you can retain only the largest terms.

In your equation, you have two terms $O(dx)$ and the other two $O(dx^2)$, $O(dy^2)$ the goes to zero faster, as the volume goes to zero.

### Some details

For the full balance equation of the elementary volume, you should consider the following terms:

- time derivative of angular momentum (and the relative flux if the volume we use is not a material volume);
- moment of surface stress;
- moment of volume force.

Anyway, for an elementary volume (whose volume "goes to zero") it's possible to think at the orders of these terms in as the linear dimension $d\ell$ of the elementary volume goes to zero, and retain only the dominant contributions. Namely:

- time derivative of angular momentum (and the relative flux if the volume we use is not a material volume) is of order $O(d\ell^4)$, three dimensions coming from the density times volume, one from the distance from the pole $P$;
- volume force term has order $O(d\ell^4)$ as well, for the same reason;
- surface stress contributions have contributions of different orders

  - pressure (and normal stress, in general) net contribution is of order $O(d\ell^4)$, see below
  - shear stress contributions is of order $O(d\ell^3)$.

Thus, explicitly writing only this last contribution, we get

$0 = \left[ \tau_{xy} - \tau_{yx} \right]dxdydz + O(d\ell^4)$

and thus the symmetry condition for the stress tensor.

**Pressure net contribution is $O(d\ell^4)$.** Let's evaluate the contribution to moment around $P$ of the $y$-component of the pressure (and more generally, normal stresses $\tau_{yy}$) on the elementary volume.

This is the sum of the contributions coming from the upper and the lower surfaces, i.e.

$[P - (P + P_{/y} dy)] dx dz \dfrac{dx}{2} = - P_{/y} dy dx dz \dfrac{dx}{2} = O(d \ell^4) $

Comment: Mmm ok thank you it is all about neglecting higher orders. So in my balance with respect to C, if I remove higher order I get $\tau_{xy}dx= \tau_{yx}dy$. The shear are the same only if dx and dy are the same. Well if they go to zero at the same rate their ratio is not 1, is it? Also, it feels to me that assuming symmetric stresses is not correct when we discretize the system of PDE on a elongated rectangular cell, cause dx is not equal to dx at all. Any thoughts?

Comment: You did something wrong if you have $dx$ on one side and $dy$ on the other side. I'm pretty sure you should get the same elementary dimensions, and those must be equal to $dx dy$. Remember that the elementary moment comes from the product of the stress and the elementary surface where the stress acts, times the distance from the pole.

Comment: its not wrong. its pretty straightforward, with respect to point C, $\tau_{xy}$ has arm dx/2 and $\tau_{yx}$ has arm dy/2, you can see it in my drawing. dx and dy do not simplify

Comment: Oh shoot I should not balance stresses but forces, so I need to multiply by the area. you are right thank you

Comment: Final thing: is it correct to say that the face of the cube doesn't have to rotate because we are considering a fixed cube in space?

Comment: it could rotate, since the average rotation of a volume of fluid is proportional to the vorticity, i.e. the curl of the velocity field. The symmetry of the stress tensor comes from the equations for the angular momentum for the elementary volume, retaining only the leading terms. Maybe, vorticity equation may be derived from the terms of order $O(d \ell^4)$. It could be, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: If you're fine with the answer to this question, please accept it and open another question about the dynamical equation for the rotation of material particles, so that we don't go off-topics here

Comment: The element is fixed because we are using an Eulerian approach. I think it is correct to say that you set the sum of angular momentum to zero becuase the Eulerian element is fixed in space. Why am I wrong with that?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant. Ok, the volume is fixed, in a Eulerian approach. But that is only a geometrical volume, we use to describe the physical process. On the other side, fluid can flow within it and across its boundary. It would be like you say that the stresses in the fluid are zero, since you're using an Eulerian volume fixed in space to describe it

Comment: I do not agree. I decide it is a fixed control volume and therefore it cannot rotate by definition.

Comment: do what you like, but equations and physics are invariant with respect to the description you give